# how function pg_ls_dir () work in postgresql 8.0.6?

Tags: postgresql

Behold, I send such a request to the database

```
select pg_ls_dir('. . . /data/pg_log/') as files_dir;
```

and I get an answer here:

```
ERROR:  function pg_ls_dir("unknown") does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.
```

It says here that there is no function version of postgresql c I work with (8.0.6), is there any way to connect to the desired function, or the other way is even files from the directory?

Comment: You should upgrade to an up-to-date Postgres version **now**.

Comment: Version 8.0 is (today) almost 10 years old and already 4 years unsupported. Do yourself a favor and use a newer (supported) version.

Answer (score 0):

The `pg_ls_dir()` function was introduced in PostgreSQL 8.1 so it's not available in 8.0.

You could try adding the function to the installation manually but I would advise against it. Here's the source regardless: http://doxygen.postgresql.org/builtins_8h.html#a35b15cee7a44663710a7125c5b57484d

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
Well, I thought somehow it perehetrit, or some other way?
I just need to read the log files from the directory, and unfortunately I can not upgrade.

Comment: @EbaaSd: I've added a link to the source. You could try to add the function but it's a bad idea. You really should look into upgrading to a newer release of Postgres regardless

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're using an old version of Postgres. `pg_ls_dir()` appeared in version 8.1.

I would strongly suggest you upgrade to the latest version (9.3 as of this writing) if at all possible, as version 8.0 is nine years old and no longer supported.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
Well, I thought somehow it perehetrit, or some other way?
I just need to read the log files from the directory, and unfortunately I can not upgrade.